# What is my mistake in creating the uv map of the lantern?

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, uv, texture-baking

I am trying to make a uv lantern for substance painter use, but I keep running into problems. [image]

[image]

this is uv map of this lantern
After separating the seams, I encounter gaps in the SP, it looks like a hard joint, but without separating into seams, it does not work out to make the correct UV map.[image]

[image]
uv without manually specified seams (I used the  smart uv project function)[image] I would be very grateful if someone could tell me what to do. maybe someone can suggest good guides for creating uv? I certainly found a few videos on YouTube, but they are all very superficial and almost useless.

Answer (score 1):

First , I see some Overlapped UV islands (may I wrong because of image size).

Second , you should use a checker map to check your UV

[image]

[image]

then in Substance painter for some materials and texture coordinate you should change Projection on UV or Tri-Planer

[image]